# $project / $addField with field name (path) contains . or $

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having issues with projecting some fields with mongodb `$project`

my colection has the following datas

```js
[{num:"SI-0101",mob:6289141515},...]
```

and my `$project`  query

```js
[{
  $project: {
    "Id No.": "$num",
    "Mobile No.": "$mob" // note on that ., i need it in o/p
  }
}]
```

When I execute this, it raise error says *`Field path not ends with .`*

How I resolve this ?

Comment: Just change the name of the field in the query. You can edit the response after the query, using your code, if you must...

Comment: @nimrodserok can you please explain with a code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$setField` to achieve such behaviour if you are using MongoDB v5.0+

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $setField: {
        field: "Id No.",
        input: "$$ROOT",
        value: "$num"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $setField: {
        field: "Mobile No.",
        input: "$$ROOT",
        value: "$mob"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "num",
      "mob"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jL5p-UTL-sF)

Comment: thanks, i also just known about this, but my question is, is this optimal way ?, image if i have 1000 docs in the collection, then i think it will be more time consuming.
anyway thanks for the answer

Comment: @codeguard That depends on your definition of *optimal*. In terms of performance, I think it is similar to a plain `$project`, which shouldn't be a burden.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb does not support keys that end with a dot (`.`). You can edit it in your code after the query. For example:

```
const userRes = await userModel.findOne({num:"SI-0101"}, {num: 1, mob: 1}).lean();
return {'Id No.': userRes.num, 'Mobile No.': userRes.mob}
```

Comment: I thought that, but imagine if i have 1000 docs then its time consuming